# How can I have left-aligned wrapped images in some paragraphs in a two-column text layout?

Tags: two-column, wrapfigure, includegraphics

I have a two-column layout for my text and I want to have a image glossary where each image in the glossary has a single paragraph description and a the image wrapped to the left of the text.

I have something that sort of works, but fails when the paragraph text is too short. See below. The image with the leading boldface text **Another yellow lion** has only four lines of text which seems to cause the next paragraph (**Another purple lion**) and its image to get messed up.

I assume I somehow need to make each paragraph and its associated image an environment in some way. I've experimented with the "environment" `\begin`  and `\end` commands as well as with the `\parbox` and `\vspace`commands, but can't seem to get it right.

I've also defined a command `lionimage` for the typesetting of each image.

```
% This is a test for having leading wrapped images in paragraphs with wrapped text around them.
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % For wrapping images in text
\usepackage{graphicx} % For images
\graphicspath{{./}} % This is where we keep our images
\usepackage{multicol} % For having two-columns in TOC and in text

% Set page layout so it looks good with two columns and small font
\usepackage[asymmetric,hcentering]{geometry}
\hoffset = -30pt
\textwidth = 490pt
\voffset = -30pt
\textheight = 660pt 

% Make sure text paragraphs have no leading indent and set the distance between paragraphs
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.6em}

% Attempt to write a LaTeX command for displaying wrapped images in paragraph text.
\newcommand*{\lionimage}[2]{%
  \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{#2}
    \vspace{-10pt}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=#2]{#1}}
    \vspace{-18pt}
  \end{wrapfigure}
}

\begin{document}

\small{}
\begin{multicols*}{2}

\section{A symbol glossary of lions}

Here is a glossary of lion symbols.

\lionimage{share-latex-lion-yellow-background.jpeg}{44pt}
\textbf{Yellow lion} This is some extremely important and interesting text on the importance of latex lion images and using latex to display them. Most importantly we want each text paragraph to begin with a wrapped image of the lion image with a colored background. We will be using different colors just for the heck of it and in order to make this example a little more interesting. I mean what could be more interesting than latex lion images with differently colored backgrounds?

\lionimage{share-latex-lion-purple-background.jpeg}{44pt}
\textbf{Purple lion} We want our images to have a thin black border around them with no padding space between the images and the border. We want to have more horizontal space between the image and the text. We want the top of the image to roughly align with the top of the paragraph text and finally, we want to remove the large space underneath the image.

\lionimage{share-latex-lion-yellow-background.jpeg}{44pt}
\textbf{Another yellow lion} Now we don't have that much text with our yellow lion image and everything goes pear-shaped in a disappointing way with the next paragraph!

\lionimage{share-latex-lion-purple-background.jpeg}{44pt}
\textbf{Another purple lion} Ok, why does our purple lion images suddenly skedaddle off and end up much further down in a place where it shouldn't be at all? Hey, come back up here with the text you belong to! 

A new paragraph with some more text that doesn't define anything in the glossary and shouldn't have a wrapped image.

And yet another paragraph that doesn't define anything in the glossary and shouldn't have a wrapped image.

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here are the two lion images:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `insbox` instead of `wrapfig` here. `wrapfig` doesn't always position the image just where you want, and while `insbox` is a lot simpler in its approach (which might have its own drawbacks) it gets the job perfectly done in this case. Note that `insbox` is not a LaTeX package, but generic code (meaning it isn't meant for LaTeX directly). The behaviour of `insbox` when two of the boxes would collide is to move below the previous box first and put everything that follows there (contrarily to `wrapfig` which will only move the figure).

As code:

```latex
% This is a test for having leading wrapped images in paragraphs with wrapped text around them.
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} % For images
\graphicspath{{./}} % This is where we keep our images
\usepackage{multicol} % For having two-columns in TOC and in text

\input{insbox} % instead of wrapfig

% Set page layout so it looks good with two columns and small font
\usepackage[asymmetric,hcentering]{geometry}
\hoffset = -30pt
\textwidth = 490pt
\voffset = -30pt
\textheight = 660pt 

% Make sure text paragraphs have no leading indent and set the distance between paragraphs
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.6em}

% Attempt to write a LaTeX command for displaying wrapped images in paragraph text.
\newcommand*{\lionimage}[2]{%
  \InsertBoxL{0}
    {%
      \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
      \fbox{\includegraphics[width=#2,height=#2]{#1}}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\small{}
\begin{multicols*}{2}

\section{A symbol glossary of lions}

Here is a glossary of lion symbols.

\lionimage{example-image-duck}{44pt}
\textbf{Yellow lion} This is some extremely important and interesting text on the importance of latex lion images and using latex to display them. Most importantly we want each text paragraph to begin with a wrapped image of the lion image with a colored background. We will be using different colors just for the heck of it and in order to make this example a little more interesting. I mean what could be more interesting than latex lion images with differently colored backgrounds?

\lionimage{example-image-duck}{44pt}
\textbf{Purple lion} We want our images to have a thin black border around them with no padding space between the images and the border. We want to have more horizontal space between the image and the text. We want the top of the image to roughly align with the top of the paragraph text and finally, we want to remove the large space underneath the image.

\lionimage{example-image-duck}{44pt}
\textbf{Another yellow lion} Now we don't have that much text with our yellow lion image and everything goes pear-shaped in a disappointing way with the next paragraph!

\lionimage{example-image-duck}{44pt}
\textbf{Another purple lion} Ok, why does our purple lion images suddenly skedaddle off and end up much further down in a place where it shouldn't be at all? Hey, come back up here with the text you belong to! 

A new paragraph with some more text that doesn't define anything in the glossary and shouldn't have a wrapped image.

And yet another paragraph that doesn't define anything in the glossary and shouldn't have a wrapped image.

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

(note that I was too lazy to download your figures and used some which are contained in the LaTeX distribution, which aren't square, hence I also added `height=#2` to `\includegraphics`)

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I get better results working with `insbox`, but I still haven't managed to completely solve my problem.

Comment: @PaulCohen what's still missing?

Comment: There's too much space below the images and the distance between the paragraph is to tight. I haven't had time to experiment more on this these last days.

Comment: @PaulCohen `\InsertBoxL` has an optional argument that follows the second argument. That optional argument is the correction of lines to be affected.

Answer (score 1):

The best result so far to my problem has been to:

- Create an environment for each image and its associated text. It's called `lion-description` below.
- In case that the image text is short, add a strut (a rule with no width but a certain height) with the required height directly after each image environment, in order to space the following image or paragraph at a suitable distance. That is the line with `\rule[11pt]{0pt}{\baselineskip}` directly after the third `lion-description` environment below.

I would like to have an environment where the suitable height of the strut is automtically calculated, based on the number of lines of text. But my knowledge of Latex is too rudimentary for that!

```
% This is a test for having leading wrapped images in paragraphs with wrapped text around them.
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % For wrapping images in text
\usepackage{graphicx} % For images
\graphicspath{{./}} % This is where we keep our images
\usepackage{multicol} % For having two-columns in TOC and in text

% Set page layout so it looks good with two columns and small font
\usepackage[asymmetric,hcentering]{geometry}
\hoffset = -30pt
\textwidth = 490pt
\voffset = -30pt
\textheight = 660pt 

% Make sure text paragraphs have no leading indent and set the distance between paragraphs
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.6em}

% Attempt to write a LaTeX command for displaying wrapped images in paragraph text.
\newcommand*{\lionimage}[2]{%
  \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{#2}
    \vspace{-10pt}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=#2]{#1}}
    \vspace{-18pt}
  \end{wrapfigure}
}

\newenvironment{lion-description}[3]{%
  \lionimage{#2}{44pt}
  \textbf{#1} #3
}

\begin{document}

\small{}
\begin{multicols*}{2}

\section{A symbol glossary of lions}

Here is a glossary of lion symbols.

\begin{lion-description}
{Yellow lion}{share-latex-lion-yellow-background.jpeg}
{This is some extremely important and interesting text on the importance of latex lion images and using latex to display them. Most importantly we want each text paragraph to begin with a wrapped image of the lion image with a colored background. We will be using different colors just for the heck of it and in order to make this example a little more interesting. I mean what could be more interesting than latex lion images with differently colored backgrounds?}
\end{lion-description}

\begin{lion-description}
{Purple lion}{share-latex-lion-purple-background.jpeg}
{We want our images to have a thin black border around them with no padding space between the images and the border. We want to have more horizontal space between the image and the text. We want the top of the image to roughly align with the top of the paragraph text and finally, we want to remove the large space underneath the image.}
\end{lion-description}

\begin{lion-description}
{Another yellow lion}{share-latex-lion-yellow-background.jpeg}
{Now we only have a short text.}
\end{lion-description}
\rule[11pt]{0pt}{\baselineskip}

\begin{lion-description}
{Another purple lion}{share-latex-lion-purple-background.jpeg}
{Ok, why does our purple lion images suddenly skedaddle off and end up much further down in a place where it shouldn't be at all? Hey, come back up here with the text you belong to!}
\end{lion-description}

A new paragraph with some more text that doesn't define anything in the glossary and shouldn't have a wrapped image.

And yet another paragraph that doesn't define anything in the glossary and shouldn't have a wrapped image.

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]